# Null check: Which is a good form?

Tags: java

Consider the following code:

```
 private List<TestDTO> types;

    if(!getTest().contains(type)) {
        return Color.LIGHT_GRAY;
    }
    return Color.BLACK;


public List<TestDTO> getTest() {
    if (types== null) {
        types= new ArrayList<TestDTO>();
    }
    return types;
}
```

Should I keep the null check inside the if condition or is it good to have a separate method for checking the null and initializing the List, as shown above?

Comment: You could also avoid `null` by initializing your variables correctly. But an own method could be better for that, to avoid duplicated `null` checks.

Comment: My experience is that when you have code like this--"initialize something if it's not already initialized"--it's done in multiple methods.  In that case it's definitely a good idea to make it a separate private method.

Comment: The getter method `getTest()` can also be used further in the code right? @ajb

Comment: Sure, why not?  One thing to keep in mind is that if you have a setup method, and you call it more than once (because one public method calls another public method and both of them call your setup method), it's OK because extra calls will have no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a design question that depends on your code base. Having the getter check for existence guarantees that you never return a null, and this is a very nice guarantee to have.

If it in a large code base for an already existing class, it can create redundant code in a lot of places.

From looking at your code, all you are doing is initializing a container, so I would say it is a good choice to make. It could avoid a bug in the future.